# What is the meaning of the word glorify in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

```
 1. Definitions of the word Transfigure I found:
    ◦ Google definition for ‘’transfigure” 
      transform into something more beautiful or **elevated**.
    ◦ TFD definition for ‘’transfigure”
        ▪ To change the form or appearance of; transform.
        ▪ To **exalt** or **glorify**
        ▪ To become or cause to become more **exalted**.
        ▪ To change so as to **glorify** or **exalt**
```

So according to this if something is transfigured it is either made more beautiful, **exalted**, or **glorified**. This is where my problem is. I know that the word "**exalted**" means:
Elevated in rank, character, or status. (TFD def) but the word "**glorify**" means:
caused to seem more important or splendid than reality; worshipped, praised, or extolled. (TFD def).
So basically the word **exalted** conveys the actual change in a person or thing and the word **glorify** only a superficial one. So it seems like both exalted and glorified can't be synonyms for transfigured yet TFD says they are. Anyone?

OK, a slight correction to the research I included.Actually the word "glorify" as a verb has a meaning of "elevate"
TFD def for "glorify"
2. **To cause to be** or seem **more glorious or excellent** than is actually the case: a description that glorified a cabin into a mansion.

So now the only question which boggles my mind is why TFD dictionary doesn't include this meaning in the adjective form of the word glorify. Or maybe the adjective "glorified" doesn't convey the same meaning as its verb form?

Comment: The root of "glorify" is "glory". You may want to look it up.

Comment: In many contexts there's no significant difference between ***exalted*** and ***glorified***. But it's probably worth noting that whereas both are perfectly common as Past Participles used adjectivally, the actual *verb* usage of ***to exalt*** is far less common that ***to glorify***. Also note that ***glorify*** is often used sarcastically or with other negative implications, as in *This movie glorifies war*, but that kind of use isn't at all common with ***exalt***.

Comment: The main point here is that "exalt" & "glorify" are both listed as the definition for the word "transfigure" but only the word exalt has the meaning of raising in rank, character, or status, and the synonym for it is "to elevate" which would fit to the Google definition i included at the very top. The word glorify doesn't mean elevate as far as I know. That's what i don't know. as for the example you provided "This movie glorifies war" it concerns a different meaning than "elevate". It means, make something to seem better that it really is. Still hope there will be someone able to explain it..

Comment: K, a slight correction to the research i included.Actually the word "glorify" as a verb has a meaning of "elevate"
TFD def for "glorify"
2. **To cause to be** or seem **more glorious or excellent** than is actually the case: a description that glorified a cabin into a mansion.

So now the only question which boggles my mind is why TFD dictionary doesn't include this meaning in the adjective form of the word glorify. Or maybe the adjective "glorified" doesn't convey the same meaning as its verb form?

Comment: How about this from Oxford dictionaries: _(of something or someone ordinary or unexceptional) represented as or appearing more elevated or special than is the case.
"I did the paperwork and was basically a glorified secretary"_?

Comment: Kate Bunting- I know that definition of the word. That's the entire problem. Definition of the word "transfigure" lists both "glorify" & "exalt" as synonyms for "transfigure", but they don't mean the same thing(although I suspect they might but no one confirmed this for me yet). Maybe it would be easier if I asked "What is the meaning of the word transfigure, other than transforming into something more beautiful in appearance, and how the word "glorify" fits into all of this. Hope this makes sense.